# Modularize routes in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is there a way with react-router to modularise your routes, then just import them and assemble them?

So instead of this:

```
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox}>
        <Route path="messages/" component={AllMessages} />
        <Route path="messages/:id" component={Message} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="calendar" component={Calendar}>
        <Route path="year" component={Year}>
          <Route path="month" component={Month}>
            <Route path="week" component={Week}/>
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

You could do something like that:

```
let InboxRoutes = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox}>
        <Route path="messages/" component={AllMessages} />
        <Route path="messages/:id" component={Message} />
      </Route>
    );
  }
});

<Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <InboxRoutes/>
      <CalendarRoutes/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

I get:
`Warning: Location did not match any routes`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One solution is to wrap them in variables:

```
let InboxRoutes = (
    <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox}>
        <Route path="messages/" component={AllMessages} />
        <Route path="messages/:id" component={Message} />
    </Route>
)

let CalendarRoutes = (/* define routes like above */)

let routes = (
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            {InboxRoutes}
            {CalendarRoutes}
        </Route>
    </Router>
)

render(routes, document.getElementById("app"))
```

*Note: You should remember to put in the render method of parent routes `{this.props.children}`*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load your routes on demand, you can do that automatically if you use Webpack.

Here's the complete guide: [Automatic Code Splitting for React Router](https://medium.com/modus-create-front-end-development/automatic-code-splitting-for-react-router-w-es6-imports-a0abdaa491e9#.elne5jmmg)

To sum it up, you'd set your routes up with getter functions that would automatically load chunks when needed.

```js
import App from 'containers/App';
function errorLoading(err) {
  console.error('Dynamic page loading failed', err);
}
function loadRoute(cb) {
  return (module) => cb(null, module.default);
}
export default {
  component: App,
  childRoutes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      getComponent(location, cb) {
        System.import('pages/Home')
          .then(loadRoute(cb))
          .catch(errorLoading);
      }
    },
    {
      path: 'blog',
      getComponent(location, cb) {
        System.import('pages/Blog')
          .then(loadRoute(cb))
          .catch(errorLoading);
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but it's kind of hacky - due to the hacky nature of react router v3.  See my answer on a similar question:

[React-router import routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048738/react-router-import-routes/39598797#39598797)