# React-router import routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I would like to change this:

```js
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={Layout}>
      <Route path='signup' component={SignupPage} />
      <Route path='assemblies/' component={AssemblyPages}>
        <Route path='categories/' component={Categories}>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

To

```js
import AssembliesRoute from './AssembliesRoute';

   <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={Layout}>
      <Route path='signup' component={SignupPage} />
      <AssembliesRoute />
    </Route>
  </Router>

//AssembliesRoute.js

export default class extends compondent {
render(){
  return <Route path='assemblies/' component={AssemblyPages}>
            <Route path='categories/' component={Categories}>
         </Route>
}
}
```

Basically, I want to take all of the routes nested inside the assemblies route, and deal with them in a specific file in the assemblies folder, and then return those routes to the Router. But when I try to do this, I get no route found. Is this possible?

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34434835/modularize-routes-in-react-router/34439180#34439180

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem with React Router is that you cannot pass it a Component that wraps a Route.

So, if you create a Component called AssemblyRoutes that wraps all your assemblies, it won't work.

What you can do is pass a function that returns the raw Route Components like so:

```
//AssemblyRoutes
    export default function(){
     return <Route ... >
    }
```

and then call the function in your routes

```
import assemblyRoutes from 'AssemblyRoutes
<Router>
 <Route>
  {assemblyRoutes()}
 </Route>
</Router>
```

And voila, you can import routes into your main routes page.

Comment: can you share a ref that explains why Routes cannot be wrapped in another Component?

Comment: I didn't find anything in the docs. Thats the perplexing thing about this issue.  This solution works for me, so I use it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the `component={AssembliesRoute}` part.  Basically, you're telling react router that the component it should render as the base for the assemblies routes is a list of routes, which, for obvious reasons, won't work.  What I *think* you can do is make `AssembliesRoute` a React component that returns a list of routes and then imbed that inside of the `Router` hierarchy.  Like this:

```
// AssembliesRoutes.js
class AssembliesRoutes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Route path='assemblies/' component={AssemblyPages}>
        <Route path='categories/' component={AssemblyCategoriesPages}>
          <Route path='create' component={AssemblyCategoriesCreatePage} />
          <Route path='index' component={AssemblyCategoriesIndexPage} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='create' component={AssemblyCreatePage} />
        <Route path='index/:categoryId' component={AssemblyIndexPage} />
      </Route>
    )
  }
}

// In your Router file
import AssembliesRoutes from './AssembliesRoutes';

<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path='/' component={Layout}>
    <Route path='signup' component={SignupPage} />
    <Route path='graphs' component={GraphShowPage} />
    <AssembliesRoutes />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Comment: Hey Taylor, I completely screwed this question up. What you put is what I had essentially done. Can you check m edits and confirm?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't work.  You need a function to directly return a Route component, not a component that wraps your route component.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a custom Route component. It's kind of hacky because react-router v3 is hacky, but it's possible. Here is an example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { IndexRoute, Route } from 'react-router';
import { createRoutesFromReactChildren } from 'react-router/lib//RouteUtils';

const CrudRoute = () => <div>&lt;CrudRoute&gt; elements are for configuration only and should not be rendered</div>;

CrudRoute.createRouteFromReactElement = (element, parentRoute) => {
    const { path, list, edit, create, remove } = element.props;
    // dynamically add crud routes
    const crudRoute = createRoutesFromReactChildren(
        <Route path={path}>
            <IndexRoute component={list} />
            <Route path="create" component={create} />
            <Route path=":id" component={edit} />
            <Route path=":id/remove" component={remove} />
        </Route>,
        parentRoute
    )[0];
    // higher-order component to pass path as resource to components
    crudRoute.component = ({ children }) => (
        <div>
            {React.Children.map(children, child => React.cloneElement(child, { path }))}
        </div>
    );
    return crudRoute;
};

export default CrudRoute;
```

Use this custom route as follows:

```js
import CrudRoute from './CrudRoute';
<Router history={history}>
    <CrudRoute path="posts" list={PostList} create={PostCreate} edit={PostEdit} remove={PostRemove} />
    <CrudRoute path="comments" list={CommentList} create={CommentCreate} edit={CommentEdit} remove={CommentRemove} />

</Router>
```

More details on this technique here: http://marmelab.com/blog/2016/09/20/custom-react-router-component.html

React-router v4 will make it extremely easy, since the `<Route>` fake component disappears and leaves way to a true React `<Match>` component.

Comment: And I realize this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34434835/modularize-routes-in-react-router/34439180#34439180, which is older. I'll copy my answer there.