# Import routes in React with react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am starting with React and trying to separate the routes into their respective files. I am using react router v6.

So I want to import the admin routes in my routes.jsx like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter, Routes, Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import AdminRoutes from './admin/adminRoutes';

const routes = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <AdminRoutes />
      <Route path="/home" element="User template" />
      <Route path="/" element="Login Template" />
      <Route path="/register" element="Register Template" />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default routes;
```

and in my adminRoutes.jsx I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const adminRoutes = () => (
  <Route path="admin/*">
    <Route path="countries" element="countries" />
    <Route path="tournaments" element="Tournaments" />
  </Route>
);

export default adminRoutes;
```

I get the error:

> Error: [adminRoutes] is not a < Route> component. All component
> children of < Routes> must be a < Route > or < React.Fragment >

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` v6 the `Routes` component can have ***only*** `Route` or `React.Fragment` as children, and `Route` components only `Routes` or other `Route` components as parent. It's an invariant RRDv6 enforces.

Convert `adminRoutes` into a React component and ***ensure*** the routed components are rendered on the `element` prop as JSX. React component names use PascalCase. Move the `path="/admin/*"` to `Routes` component which will render this component.

```
const AdminRoutes = () => (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="countries" element="countries" />
    <Route path="tournaments" element="Tournaments" />
  </Routes>
);

export default AdminRoutes;
```

Render `AdminRoutes` into the router on its own route.

```
const Routes = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/admin/*" element={<AdminRoutes />} />
      <Route path="/home" element="User template" />
      <Route path="/" element="Login Template" />
      <Route path="/register" element="Register Template" />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Demo opens to `"/admin/countries"` and renders "countries".

[image: Edit import-routes-in-react-with-react-router]

Comment: What happens if we have some part of the application that has some components, each one with a different route? Like a folder named `forms` where we put all our forms but none of them follow any URL pattern (one can be `/admin/edit-form`, the other one `/profile/change-password`, the other one `/contact`...). I'd like to keep all form-routes inside the same `FormRoutes` component for the sake of organization, but they do not share any common path.

Comment: @Unapedra Are you referring to the directory/file structure for how you are organizing your code in your project? That hasn't much to do with route rendering and navigation. You can render any React component on any Route, regardless where the component is declared or its file is stored in the project.

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because

```
const adminRoutes = () => (
  <Route path="admin/*">
    <Route path="countries" element="countries" />
    <Route path="tournaments" element="Tournaments" />
  </Route>
);
```

when you are doing this, you are creating a standalone `Component` that underwent all the things a React Component do, and thus `react-router-dom` is not accepting it.

For explanation, let's suppose if you treat it as a valid option to be used as a child of `Routes` as it is only returning `<Route/>` from it, but here one thing to notice is, you can add all the `hooks` like useEffect and all which makes it more than just a `<Route />` and because of this reason, `react-router-dom` is not allowing it.

What you can do is, instead of exporting it as a `React Component`, you can export it as a `React Element` and this will be allowed.

```
const AdminRoutes = (<Routes>
    <Route path="countries" element="countries" />
    <Route path="tournaments" element="Tournaments" />
  </Routes>);

export default AdminRoutes;
```

and then use it as `{AdminRoutes}` inside the `<Routes></Routes>`.

Here is an example code https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-swartz-ikqdn?file=/src/App.js . Goto `/te` to see it working.

You can read more about `Element` and `Component` at https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html .

`Note: Follow the consecutive links to know about component and difference as well.`

Comment: Furthermore to this solution, which works like a charm, you can also follow this other approach which is very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048738/react-router-import-routes/35133868#35133868

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. You should wrap with Routes component when import another route.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter, Routes, Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import AdminRoutes from './admin/adminRoutes';

const routes = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <AdminRoutes />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/home" element="User template" />
      <Route path="/" element="Login Template" />
      <Route path="/register" element="Register Template" />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default routes;
```

and

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

const adminRoutes = () => (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="admin/*">
      <Route path="countries" element="countries" />
      <Route path="tournaments" element="Tournaments" />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
);

export default adminRoutes;
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-22krj?file=/public/index.html)

Comment: HI, I tried this and now I have this error:

Error: AdminRoutes(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

Comment: Can you check the demo i attached